# Integrate maven project to an eclipse plug-in project ( RCP application )

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have a backend that is a maven project, and i want to create a frontend RCP application that uses the maven project. how to add the maven project and all the dependencies to my rcp plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

Your Maven project as well as its dependencies should be [converted to OSGI bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235129/how-can-i-share-non-osgi-libraries-between-bundles-in-an-osgi-container/1235145#1235145) before they can be used by your RCP application. If you wish to use Maven for building Eclipse RCP, have a look at [Tycho](http://www.eclipse.org/proposals/tycho/).