# Add struts plugin at runtime

Tags: java, struts2, osgi

I want to build a modular webapp with struts.

Struts provide modules as Pluing. Plugin set are placed in the WEB-INF/lib war's directory, but you cannot modify this configuration at runtime. i.e: downloading a plugin from a remote server or uploading the plugin into the webapp itself.

I read the osgi struts plugin documentation. It focuses on start an ogsi container and let actions access the osgi services.

There isn't any project to let struts plugin be deployed as osgi bundle?

Comment: Adding/removing plugin means add/remove features to webapp (menu item, pages, etc..)

Comment: I found this old articles: http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/08/struts2OSGi http://blogs.atlassian.com/2007/07/osgi_plugin_for_struts_2_lesso/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Struts 2 available as an OSGi bundle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892000/is-struts-2-available-as-an-osgi-bundle)